# Ruby string does not match expression

Tags: ruby

I have this ruby expression as below

```
  (a|bc)(d?|e)*
```

when i use rubular to test out possible strings that fit this expression, I have some strings that I dont understand why they dont fit

the strings are "ade", it matches "ad" but does not match the "e". Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of the regular expression you entered (d?|e)* is the problem.  Putting the ? on the d says, match d 0 or 1 times.  When you run through the string ade, the regex matches a, then d, then d 0 times...  If you instead changed it to (a|bc)(d|e)*, it would match ade, and seem to have the semantics that you're looking for.

Comment: just wondering, so any part of the string that contains an e will not match the regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

(d?)* is a non-greedy match and e* will be "short circuited" by logic or. It will match as few as possible.

I don't know why you put a question mark there. Just use

```
(a|bc)(d|e)*
```

Will be fine.